# Form Submission to two different location

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a list of check boxes. I want to check them and submit.

1. I should be able to check 2 entries and and submit it to compare.php
2. or i should be able to check one and send it to insert.php.

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can, though perhaps the logic to determine the flow should be on the server side (clients have a habit of sending bad things, which you can deal with on the server-side).

I would use jQuery, though native Javascript would work fine (it'd be more complicated, though).

I'd do something like:

```
<form id="myForm"></form>
<script type="text/javscript">
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  // Look at form inputs here and set the form action accordingly.
  // Note: 'this' refers to the form DOM element.
  this.setAttribute('action', 'myurl.php');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a frame and do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to do this.  Have you form action point to a JS function that would do something like:

```
if(checkbox1.checked==1 && checkbox2.checked==1) {
     //ajax request to compare.php
} else if(checkbox1.checked==1 || checkbox2.checked==1) {
     //ajax request to insert.php
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy. was wondering if i could do it with out ajax :D

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using AJAX form submit